# Match #include tags with regex

Tags: c++, regex, notepad++

I'm using the Find and Replace feature in Notepad++ and though I've never used regex before, I don't see any other way of accomplishing my goal here.  I'm trying to select only two specific characters, only in lines that feature a specific word.  The specific word is `#include`, and the specific characters are `<` and `>`

So for instance, if I have `#include <climits>`, I want to match only the `<` and `>`.

If I have a line such as `template<class T>` I do not want to select anything on that line, because it does not contain `#include` in the line.

Any suggestions?

Edit for specificity:
I'm less worried about the `<` character since I think I can just use find and replace to fix those, so I'm just just going to request that we focus on the `>` character at this point.  Here's an example of what I'm trying to do.  Currently one of my .hpp files contains:

```
#include "utility> //for std::swap (C++11)
#include "algorithm> //for std::swap (C++98)
#include "cstddef> //for std::size_t
#include "boost/config.hpp"
```

Which I'd like to change to

```
#include "utility" //for std::swap (C++11)
#include "algorithm" //for std::swap (C++98)
#include "cstddef" //for std::size_t
#include "boost/config.hpp"
```

Other parts of this code contain things that I'd like not to change at all, despite containing the `>` character:

```
template<class Alloc>
    class CompatAlloc
    {        // general case : be transparent
```

I'm trying to preserve the include reference itself, i.e. what is contained within the `<` and `>` or the `"` and `>`, and the comments.  Thereby only replacing the `>` character, and where applicable, the `<` character, with `"` but only on lines that begin with `#include`.

Hope that makes it more clear, sorry for the confusion.  I am not really a programmer, just trying to help a friend compile some C++ software for Windows, though it was written with Linux in mind, so many of the include files it requires have small syntax issues with Visual C++.  So I hope you all will bear with me a bit, and I appreciate all the help :)

Comment: "I want to match only the < and >".
What do you mean?

Comment: Are you looking to match the actual `<` and `>`, or the things in between them? In a comment below you were mentioning broken include tags (`#include "foo>`). Are you looking to fix those, or are you looking to extract the names of the libraries included? Please be more specific.

Comment: I want to match the actual `<` and `>`.  I'm looking to fix the broken things, not to extract the names of the libraries.

Comment: "Not a programmer, just trying to compile C++ software for Windows"- I already had the idea that it's an XY problem. The reason it fails to compile is that `<>` headers and `""` headers are looked up in different places. `<>` is for system headers. `#include "algorithm"` is **wrong**. `<algorithm>` is part of the C++ Standard Library both on Linux and Windows, and everywhere else too.

Comment: Downvoted because of what MSalters said. The question is built on a false premise. The includes are already correct and should not be changed.

Comment: I find this rather confusing, because when I run the compiler, I can see it tells me, problem in include file x, on line y, no such file or directory.  Of course, when I navigate to said directory, I do indeed find the file where it's supposed to be.  So I looked up the usage of `<` and `>` vs. `"` and found that not only would `"` work, but that it would work better, in my current situation.

So, I would change the file, and then the compiler would be happy with it, and it would move onto the next error.  Just as I expected from the reading I'd done.

So, what is the solution, then?

Comment: The only four includes that the actual code for my friend's software has, are `#include <cmath>`, `#include <fstream>`, `#include <iostream>`, and `#include <boost/multiprecision/mpfr.hpp>`.  The compiler is unable to find these unless I change the `<` & `>` to `"`.  I assume there are other ways to tell it where to look, but my solution was working well for me, so far.

The boost directory has hundreds, if not thousands of other includes, though, which is why I was using Notepad++ to edit them in bulk.

At this point, I'm tempted to just post a separate question about it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this find and replace:

**Find:**

```
#include\s+"([^>]+)>
```

**Replace:**

```
#include "$1"
```

Note that instead of `$1`, some regex engines use `\1` as the first capture group, in which case you would replace with this:

```
#include "\1"
```

Comment: Thanks, but that appears to select the entire line, and I'm only looking to select the `<` and `>` characters.  Also, some of the lines have already been changed without using regex (rather, using find & replace) to things like `#include "cstdef>` in which case there is only the closing character, not the opening one

Comment: @CamKrout I won't update until you edit your question and show us a complete sample of data, along with what exactly you are trying to do.  My current answer is very reasonable based on your vague question.

Comment: For the broken include tags, what character(s) would be replacing the opening `<`?  Is this the only defect in your code data, or are other things broken as well?

Comment: If the intent with matching from the beginning of the line is to ensure that #include is not, say, the content of a string, you should probably restrict the `.*` to `\s*`. E.g. `^(?=\s*#include)\s*<[^>]*>$`

Comment: @SimonShine Not a C++ person, but perhaps there could be a comment happening before the `#include` directive.  If so, then using `\s*` might not cover every case.

Comment: @Tim Biegelisen Alright, I updated the question.  I'm replacing the opening `<` and the closing `>` with `"`, but not the contents of the `<` and `>`.  Also, I think I've figured out how to replace the opening `<` using find and replace, so I really just need to know how to replace the closing `>` with `"`

Comment: @CamKrout Thanks for finally nailing down your question.  I think there is an easy answer.

Answer (score 0):

To match a `<`, you can use the pattern `<`. To match only `<`s that come after an `#include`, you can add a look-behind: `(?<=#include )<`. To match the `>` after `#include <foo`, you can't use a look-behind, since they're generally not allowed to have a variable width (and the name of the include has that). If you wanted the regex for the `<` to be whitespace-sensitive (e.g. so that `#include   <foo>` would match), you've got the same problem.

Since this is a search-and-replace, perhaps you could match more than simply the `<` and `>`, but replace it with something that uses a capturing group, e.g. if you want to replace all instances of `#include <foo>` with `#include "foo"`,

Replace `^(\s*#include\s*)<([^>]*)>` with `\1 "\2"`.